# How to use authetication file with heapster

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I am running a secure kubernetes cluster where authentication is done using keystone. Now, I am trying to run heapster and I am getting the error as:

```
E0720 09:22:18.244161       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/sources/summary/summary.go:454: Failed to list *api.Node: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get nodes)
E0720 09:22:18.250826       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/processors/namespace_based_enricher.go:84: Failed to list *api.Namespace: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get namespaces)
```

I want to know how can I pass an authentication file to heapster and what should that file contain? Or is there any other way to provide credentials to heapster?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Heapster auth configuration is documented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/cd2301d0bca468dff796a9d26bc093efdcc1be2d/docs/source-configuration.md#kubernetes)

Comment: Yeah, but in place of auth it only says, "auth - client auth file to use. Set auth if the service accounts are not usable." There is no details about the format, syntax etc. of the file. What am I supposed to write in the file?